# Can you use Parse SDK with apple watch?

Tags: parse-platform, watchkit, apple-watch

Is it possible to use the Parse SDK with the new Apple WatchKit? 
If it is would it be possible to send notifications from the apple watch using parse.

I have all the architecture working on the iPhone (I can send parse push notifications from Device to Device). Is there a way to send information to iPhone from apple watch then send notification in the background using the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Parse SDK with WatchKit.  Your Watch App runs as an extension on your iPhone so you can use use any SDK that work in iOS extensions.

Comment: Do i need another bridging header in order for it to get the Parse SDK on the app extension?. Also anther thing, does this mean i could send push notifications using PFPush from the device ?

Comment: You can import Parse in your existing bridge header and you will need to link parse with your extension.  Yes you should be able to use PFPush from your extension.

Answer (score 0):

They have just released Apple Watch specific API's for their SDK.